# Android native code fork() has issues with IPC/Binder

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have an Android native Server app compiled as Platform privileged module that forks itself. This module also uses Android services, like SurfaceFlinger. I need to fork to have one sandboxed process per client.

Fork() works fine and the parent process has no issue at all. But in the child process, when I try to access any Android service/resource I get:

> signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr xxxxxxxx ... ...
>   /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::Parcel::ipcSetDataReference
>   ...
>   /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::BpBinder::transact
>   NativeCrashListener( 1203): Couldn't find ProcessRecord for pid XXXX

- This happens even when I try to create a NEW client, thus, not using any previous created reference.
- NativeCrashListener doesn't know about my child process, thus, maybe ActivityManager also doesn't.

I looked at the Zygote code but have not found anything helpful there. I'm probably missing some step or calling some function on the child process. Any ideas ??? =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't create a new Binder process this way.

The problem is that `fork()` only clones the current thread, not all threads.  In the new process, the Binder IPC code will expect the Binder helper threads to be running, but none of them will be.  You need to `fork()` and then `exec()`.

The zygote process avoids this issue by having only one thread running when `fork()` is called.  It deliberately defers initialization of the Binder code to the child process.  (In the current implementation, it actually has a couple of threads running in Dalvik, but the internal fork handling stops and restarts those threads on every fork).

Comment: Do you think it's feasible to try to do the same? Stop and restart threads or follow another approach as suggested by Digit?

Comment: You won't be able to stop and restart all of the threads in the process.  Follow digit's solution.

Answer (score 2):

fadden is right, fork() cannot be used to create a new process that uses Android APIs reliably. The best you can do with it is exec() to run a standalone command-line program, everything else is likely to not work as you expect.

However, the platform supports sandboxed processes, in the form of isolated service processes. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html#isolated for more details. In essence, this runs your service in a special process under a random UID that has no permissions.

For the record, this is what Chrome on Android uses to isolate 'tabs' into sandboxed 'renderer processes'.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I guess if Chrome uses that it's probably a good way to achieve that. I'll have a look at it if I can't "clone" Zygote's behavior.